# linuxfromscratch: Can't do make menuconfig for linux installing

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-from-scratch

On this chapter http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/kernel.html

```
root@host# chroot "$LFS" /usr/bin/env -i \
>     HOME=/root TERM="$TERM" PS1='\u:\w\$ ' \
>     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin \
>     /bin/bash --login
root:/# cd sources/linux-3.2.6
root:/sources/linux-3.2.6# make mrproper
  CLEAN   scripts/basic
  CLEAN   scripts/kconfig
  CLEAN   include/config
root:/sources/linux-3.2.6# make menuconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
```

Why am i gettting such error?

**Updating**

Got the answer, it is binutils installation related, may be corrupted installation of binutis.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gcc-error-trying-to-exec-%27as%27-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory-906750/

[`gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory` When compile program with `popen` in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878676/gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory-when-compil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install GNU Binutils package.

http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question, expecting upvote.