# Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc

I have been successfully using gcc on Linux Mint 12. Now I am getting an error. I have recently been doing some .so builds and installed Clang not to long ago, but have successfully compiled since both of those events, so not sure what has changed. I used the GUI Software Manager to remove and then install gcc again, but the results are the same:

```
~/code/c/ut: which gcc                                                                                                     
/usr/bin/gcc

~/code/c/ut: gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -c object.c                                                                      
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory\` When compile program with \`popen\` in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878676/gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory-when-compil)

Answer (score 167):

### Explanation

The error message told us, that the build-time dependency (in this case it is `cc1`) was not found, so all we need — install the appropriate package to the system (using package manager // from sources // another way)

What is `cc1`:

> `cc1` is the internal command which takes preprocessed C-language files and converts them to assembly. It's the actual part that compiles C. For C++, there's cc1plus, and other internal commands for different languages.

<sup>[taken from this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77781/144260) by [Alan Shutko](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/25945/alan-shutko).</sup>

### Solution for: Ubuntu / Linux Mint

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
```

### Solution for: Docker-alpine environment

If you are in **docker-alpine** environment install the [build-base](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=build-base) package by adding this to your `Dockerfile`:

```docker
RUN apk add build-base
```

<sup>Better package name provided by [Pablo Castellano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9829892/pablo-castellano). More [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751376/1115187).</sup>

If you need more packages for building purposes, consider adding of the [alpine-sdk](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=alpine-sdk) package:

```docker
RUN apk add alpine-sdk
```

<sup>Taken from [github](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/24#issuecomment-89771871)</sup>

### Solution for: CentOS/Fedora

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403093/1115187) contains instructions for CentOS and Fedora Linux

### Solution for: Amazon Linux

```bash
sudo yum install gcc72-c++
```

<sup>Taken from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory/44708372#comment90819578_48076977) by [CoderChris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208266/coderchris)</sup>

You could also try to install missed dependencies by this (*though, it is said to not to solve the issue*):

```bash
sudo yum install gcc-c++.noarch
```

<sup>Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48076977/1115187)</sup>

Comment: did not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: @execbook : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-on-ubuntu-20-04/ , but nothing actually changed, the same `build-essential` package resolves the problem

Comment: For Amazon Linux 2, `sudo yum install gcc72-c++` didn't work for me but `sudo yum install gcc-c++` worked fine.

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer @maxkoryukov. I did learn from it. Thank you!

Comment: In OpenSuse running `zypper install -t pattern devel_basis` won't install C++, run `zypper install gcc-c++` to add also that.

Comment: For posterity, it was trying to install python's spare-dot-topn that led me here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754148/error-installing-sparse-dot-topn-on-aws-ec2-could-not-build-wheels-for-sparse) [twice apparently]

Comment: For RHEL/8 `sudo yum install gcc-c++` worked for me.

Answer (score 104):

On CentOS or Fedora

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 73):

On debian / ubuntu I fixed this problem by reinstalling `build-essential`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
```

Comment: In the log for the ´--reinstall build-essential´ my ubuntu specifically stated
"Setting up g++ (4:6.1.1-1ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode"

Comment: This fixed me on Debian DigitalOcean.com droplet. I only had to run the second command shown though and after that gcc compiled by .cpp file perfectly.

Comment: @mchid Nothing wrong - It fixed the problem. Just wanted to clarify what part of you suggestion related to the problem. E.g. if your answer did not work for someone they could use the update-alternative specific for the gcc.

Answer (score 28):

This is because `gcc` calls many other executables to complete the processing of the input, and `cc1` is not in the included path.

On shell type `whereis cc1`. If `cc1` is found, it's better go ahead and create a softlink in the directory of `gcc`; otherwise, `cc1` is not installed and you have to install *gcc-c++* using the package manager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
whereis cc1 returns nothing. 
I have gcc and gcc-4.4, gcc-4-6, libgcc1 installed according to Software Manager. I just install g++, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: see if the executable is present in /usr/local/libexec/gcc/<architecture>/<compiler>/<compiler_version>/cc1 otherwise for temporary usage navigate to /usr/bin and create link by `ln -s cc cc1`

Comment: I don't have a /usr/local/libexec directory. There is no "gcc" found under /usr/local.

Comment: GCC is under /usr/bin and there you will cc as well,execute the command mentioned in previous comment in this directory.

Comment: I did find:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/cc1

Comment: I added the above to my path and gcc now says "gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
compilation terminated."

Comment: I don't know how this happened. I would like to remove gcc and reinstall, but doing the "remove" from the Software Manager and "Install" got me the same problem. One that I am am just now getting after months of OK usage??

Comment: The tip to install `gcc-c++` got me moving again after a day of frustration!

Comment: The cc1/cc1plus binaries are NOT supposed to be in $PATH.

Comment: Thanks!  This solution is what's needed for users of Amazon Linux - just a note to future visitors!

Answer (score 19):

> ## Amazon Linux: fixing GCC issue

Since this comes up as the first result on Google, I just wanted to document my experience with Amazon Linux. Installing `gcc-c++.noarch` fixed the problem:

`sudo yum install gcc-c++.noarch`

Some people also reported this alternative as a solution (@CoderChris):

`sudo yum install gcc72-c++`

Others reported doing `sudo yum install gcc` first, then `sudo yum install gcc-c++`. (@Wilmer E. Henao, @Talha Anwar)

Comment: Definitely my problem on amazon linux, but alas, `.noarch` is already installed.

Comment: sudo yum install gcc72-c++ 
sorted it for me on Amazon Linux

Comment: Glad somebody's talking about Amazon Linux, but neither of these solutions worked for me...

Comment: On "Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03" yum install gcc72-c++ is what I needed too.

Comment: sudo yum install gcc72-c++ works for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Try again with `yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: Thx @jtlz2, that's the one that worked for me and resolved my issue on Amazon Linux!

Answer (score 15):

I fixed this problem by explicitly installing g++:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Problem was encountered on Ubuntu 12.04 while installing pandas.  (Thanks perilbrain.)

Answer (score 14):

I ran into a similar issue today - a co-worker could not build his software but I could build it. When he ran `gcc` it could not find `cc1`.

His executable path looked reasonable but the fact that I could not easily replicate the failure suggested something in his environment as the cause.

Eventually we found `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` defined in his environment which was the culprit and was misleading `gcc` in the search for `cc1`. This was part of his shell startup scripts and was meant to work around a limitation on a SPARC/Solaris system that is no longer in use. The problem was resolved by not setting this environment variable.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html

Comment: Exact same problem.. still unresolved!
This occurred after porting the project from 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS.

Answer (score 9):

`yum install gcc-c++` 
 did the fix.

Comment: duplicate of an existing answer (currently the highest voted one, posted a year before this one).  "Thanks" or "me too" answers are just clutter.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX(env)` is not exported and your `PATH` is exported to right tool chain.

Answer (score 4):

Adding my solution for **Amazon Linux** - Working in 2021:

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

and then:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++
```

Comment: this helped me in aws lambda.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this soon after compiling and installing a shiny new GCC — version 8.1 — on RHEL 7. In the end, it ended up being a permissions problem; my root umask was the culprit. I eventually found `cc1` hiding in `/usr/local/libexec`:

```
[root@nacelle gdb-8.1]# ls -l /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/ | grep cc1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 196481344 Jul  2 13:53 cc1
```

However, the permissions on the directories leading there didn't allow my standard user account:

```
[root@nacelle gdb-8.1]# ls -l /usr/local/libexec/
total 4
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Jul  2 13:53 gcc
[root@nacelle gdb-8.1]# ls -l /usr/local/libexec/gcc/
total 4
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Jul  2 13:53 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[root@nacelle gdb-8.1]# ls -l /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/
total 4
drwxr-x--- 4 root root 4096 Jul  2 13:53 8.1.0
```

A quick recursive `chmod` to add world read/execute permissions fixed it right up:

```
[root@nacelle 8.1.0]# cd /usr/local/libexec
[root@nacelle lib]# ls -l | grep gcc
drwxr-x---  3 root root     4096 Jul  2 13:53 gcc
[root@nacelle lib]# chmod -R o+rx gcc
[root@nacelle lib]# ls -l | grep gcc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Jul  2 13:53 gcc
```

And now `gcc` can find `cc1` when I ask it to compile something!

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement @maxkoryukov's answer regarding Alpine.

The equivalent to Debian's `build-essential` in Alpine is `build-base`. In fact, the above mentioned `alpine-sdk` depends on `build-base`.

```
/ # apk info -R build-base
build-base-0.5-r1 depends on:
binutils
file
gcc
g++
make
libc-dev
fortify-headers

/ # apk info -R alpine-sdk
alpine-sdk-1.0-r0 depends on:
abuild
build-base
git
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Amazon Linux Release 2** This will solve the issue:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++
```

(This will not work: `sudo yum install gcc72-c++`)

Answer (score 1):

This might also be the displayed error message if you try to run 32-bit gcc binaries on a 64-bit OS and missing 32-bit glibc. According to this [readme](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/174121181/readme.txt): "For 64 bit system, 32 bit libc and libncurses are required to run the tools.".
In this case there is no problem with the path and cc1 is actually found, but [reported as missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716702/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-executing-a-binary) as no 32 bit glibc.

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me was to use `llvm-gcc` instead:

```
ln -s $(which llvm-gcc) /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem on a reasonably fresh install of Fedora 27.  I tried all the other suggestions or their equivalents; installing the various packages either said "already installed" or installed something new which didn't help.

Fixed with

```
# dnf remove gcc
# dnf install gcc gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 1):

On Scientific Linux 6 (similar to CentOS 6-- SL is now replaced by CentOS, AIUI), I had to use `/usr/sbin/prelink -av -mR` which I found suggested at https://stelfox.net/blog/2014/08/dependency-prelink-issues/

Until I did that, I got a cc1 error `gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory` when I tried to compile, and gcc --version reported 4.2.2 instead of 4.4.7, despite that version being reported by yum.

It may or may not be related, but the system had run out of space on /var

Answer (score 1):

Just to document my trouble with this issue even though it just appears to be a specific example of other answers; as a relative newbie I feel like this might help others.

Solution:

I added '/usr/bin' to the beginning of PATH for a single session using `PATH='/usr/path/:$PATH'` and everything started to work fine.

I used gedit to update the PATH permanently, after ensuring it wouldn't break my regular toolchains.

Explanation:

I have multiple toolchains installed on Ubuntu 14.04LTS and I use just a couple on a regular basis. When I tried to use gcc from the command line I got the issue describe by the OP. '/usr/bin' is in the PATH but it is behind the other toolchain locations. Turns out the cc1 for those other toolchains is incompatible with gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Im my rare case the PATH variable was set but not exported.
Simply exporting the PATH variable was solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some additional answer, for the ones who the most liked answer didn't help.

I accidentally deleted some of files in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/bin` so `apt` couldn't reinstall `gcc` and `build-essential` packages correctly. I've tried almost everything, but, at the end only restoring the whole dependency tree helped. On Ubuntu 20.04 I've run the following:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall \
    binutils \
    binutils-common \
    binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu \
    cpp \
    cpp-9 \
    gcc \
    gcc-10-base \
    gcc-9 \
    gcc-9-base \
    libasan5 \
    libatomic1 \
    libbinutils \
    libc-dev-bin \
    libc6 \
    libc6-dev \
    libcc1-0 \
    libcrypt-dev \
    libcrypt1 \
    libctf-nobfd0 \
    libctf0 \
    libgcc-9-dev \
    libgcc-s1 \
    libgmp10 \
    libgomp1 \
    libidn2-0 \
    libisl22 \
    libitm1 \
    liblsan0 \
    libmpc3 \
    libmpfr6 \
    libquadmath0 \
    libstdc++6 \
    libtsan0 \
    libubsan1 \
    libunistring2 \
    linux-libc-dev \
    manpages \
    manpages-dev \
    zlib1g
```

Answer (score 0):

In my rare case it was `color wrapper` who spoiled `gcc`. Solved by disabling `cw` excluding its directory `/usr/libexec/cw` from `PATH` environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why does this happen?
When you install a fresh copy of linux, gcc compiler comes pre-packed with it. It only contains the files and binaries which are used to run the linux(to save space and time, obviously).

How to solve this error?
All you need is to update your packages through the package manager and reinstall the build-essential packages.
The commands might be different on different kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example. You might find your `cc1` installed on other places depends on whatever software was installed before.

```
find /usr/ -name "*cc1*"
# out:  /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+pcc1
# out:  /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/cc1
# out: /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/cc1plus
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/
```

credit belong to programmerah

- https://programmerah.com/gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory-27405/
- https://programmerah.com/solved-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory-51267/

And of course, this is more from the Pen tester perspective. Please using proper method to resolve it like other answers mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix that by running this:
On Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config
```

Answer (score -1):

It's in this package (Ubuntu 19.04):

```
  sudo apt install g++-6
```

Comment: You don't need to install an old G++ version; just `g++` is fine.  Or better, `build-essential` pulls in some libs too.

Answer (score -1):

Documenting another source of errors for installing gcc-10 on Amazon Linux 2 from source.

After running `sudo make install` and then testing `gcc-10` I got this error:

```
gcc-10: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1’: execvp: No such file or directory
```

The reason was that the new g++ directories under `/usr/local/` were created by `sudo make install` have `700` permissions so non-root users cannot see the directories content.

I fixed it by running

```
sudo find /usr/local/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Note that I followed this snippet https://gist.github.com/nchaigne/ad06bc867f911a3c0d32939f1e930a11