# Cannot get Pandas to install ! Help! (pip install pandas)

Tags: python, linux, pandas, centos, pip

I'm trying to install Pandar but I can't get pandas to install on my linux Centos 6.4.

Running `pip install pandas` leads to this error:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im pretty sure thats a compiler error, so try installing `g++` on the system

if you are working on linux, run this.

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: Yes, I have gcc installed.

Comment: @FilipKorngut did you take a look on [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)?

Comment: Yes, just saw the comment.  Trying now.

Comment: I had g++ installed, but not of the same version as my gcc. Upgrading my g++ to match my gcc fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

or if you have a CentOS system, you might want to install `gcc`, `gcc-c++`

```
$ yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

Then install `pandas` using `pip`

```
$ pip install pandas
```