# msp430-gcc error trying to exec 'cc1':

Tags: gcc, msp430, contiki

I'm trying to compile a contiki hello-world example..

We use msp430-gcc compiler in the 4.7 version.. that I have allocated in /opt/msp430-47 folder..

after to could change the Path of mspgcc and it reconises me like 4.7 version when: msp430-gcc -v...

When I try to compile it prints me:

> using saved target 'z1'   CC        ../../core/net/rime/rimeaddr.c
>   msp430-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or
>   directory make: *** [obj_z1/rimeaddr.o] Error 1

can someone give me a hand??? On whats happening...?

Thanx!!!!

Comment: Does this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: The compiler is not installed correctly; what exactly did you do? (And `msp430-gcc` and `mspgcc`would be different pieces of software.)

Comment: What i.ve done is first install the stable version 4.6 and then download a file with a the files of the 4.7 and save them on /opt and put this on path.. wen I write msp430-gcc -v it tells me that the current version is 4.7 but then wen i compile it tells me that

Comment: I've installed the tools using


sudo apt-get install build-essential binutils-msp430 gcc-msp430 msp430-libc msp430mcu mspdebug

Comment: Could you run `make  .... V=1`. That gives a more verbose output about what's going on.

Comment: tha is what I've obtain

Comment: You shouldn't answer, but edit your question to add information. Yet in the end, it looks like there is something wrong with your installation in the opt folder. Maybe some folder missing in your PATH environment.

Comment: @morty I post an answer not in a coment because it was to long to post is the next answr :)

Comment: @morty I could solve the problem downloading again the files of contiki.. it seems than in other compilations it created a folder called obj_z1 and it was empty and it creates conflict...

Comment: @EfremBlazquez: You can edit your question; That with the folder is odd. Can you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by adding compiler path as well as cc1 path to the environment. So I added these two lines at the end in ~/.bashrc file.

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/ti/msp430-gcc/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/ti/msp430-gcc/libexec/gcc/msp430-elf/7.3.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

@morty that is what I've obtain

> using saved target 'z1' msp430-gcc -DCONTIKI=1 -DCONTIKI_TARGET_Z1=1
>   -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -mmcu=msp430f2617   -I. -I../../platform/z1/. -I../../platform/z1/dev -I../../platform/z1/apps -I../../platform/z1/net -I../../cpu/msp430/f2xxx -I../../cpu/msp430/f1xxx -I../../cpu/msp430/. -I../../cpu/msp430/dev -I../../core/dev -I../../core/lib -I../../core/net -I../../core/net/mac -I../../core/net/rime -I../../core/net/rpl -I../../core/sys -I../../core/cfs -I../../core/ctk -I../../core/lib/ctk -I../../core/loader -I../../core/. -I../../platform/z1/ -MMD -c ../../core/net/rime/rimeaddr.c -o obj_z1/rimeaddr.o msp430-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No
>   such file or directory make: *** [obj_z1/rimeaddr.o] Error 1