# error while installing "ade4" package for R language in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, package, installation

I want to install package `ade4` that is a "R" language package in ubuntu 15.10 However it gives me the following error.

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c adesub.c -o adesub.o
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I also installed `r-base-dev` package

I checked the g++ and build-install packages and both of them are installed and have the same version.
How I can solve this issue?

Comment: What does `which g++` return?

Comment: it returns /usr/bin/g++

Comment: In any case this does not seem to be a general problem of Ubuntu 15.10 or ade4. The package compiles and works on my installation of Ubuntu 15.10. Is `/usr/bin` included in the output of `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: yes it echoes it. Is there any thing with permission? I gave 777 permission to all related directories although I still have the problem

Comment: I think R-Studio does not recognize the installation path of the gcc. It is weird.

Comment: No, I don't think it's related to permissions. I believe it's a matter of `PATH`.. or some compiler-related environment variable. Does it work without RStudio, i.e., in a simple R shell?

Comment: I tried it and I got the same error

Comment: @lmo May I ask you please to up vote my question I cannot ask any more question.

Comment: do http://askubuntu.com/questions/714395/error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory-possible-sage-pyt or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory give you any clues?

Comment: @Ben Bolker thanks. I got my answer however down-vote to my question do not allow me to ask further question.

Comment: I don't see an accepted answer to this question (it doesn't seem that @DirkEddelbuettel's answer addressed your question); if the comments gave you an answer, can you post it yourself? That would be a useful way to contribute to the site/convince people to up-vote the question.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

```
 sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

which is a 'virtual' package containing only dependency information which ensures you have the compiler (via package `build-essentials`) and a number of things generally needed to build R packages.

PS There is no such thing as Ubuntu 15.1. There are 15.04 and 15.10.

Comment: Thank you but I have installed that before. yes Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: You are welcome.  Please feel free to 'accept' the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: I told I have installed it before posting this post. I have the problem. your solution did not solve my problem