# Installing package "chron" in R

Tags: r, gcc, ubuntu-14.04, chron

Running Ubuntu 14.04 and while installing the package chron on R, I get the following message:

```
* installing *source* package ‘chron’ ...
** package ‘chron’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c chron_strs.c -o chron_strs.o
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [chron_strs.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘chron’
* removing ‘/home/ncoupe/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/chron’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp1v7Xja/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("chron") :
  installation of package ‘chron’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any suggestions
Thanks
Natalia

Comment: It seems that `gcc`  can not find `cc1`. There is [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11912878/4303162) about this already.

Answer (score 2):

chron has several non R dependencies. The easiest way to install it is

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-cran-chron
```

Comment: helpful, but FWIW the OP's problem looks more like a configuration/PATH problem than a dependency problem ...

Comment: Thank you Dirk 
Thank you Dirk, the command

sudo apt-get install r-cran-chron

worked!