# Issue with cross compilation

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I would like to compile a simple test program in c with an ARM toolchain.

My Makefile is as follows:

```
CC=/project_path/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/gcc

# the compiler: gcc for C program, define as g++ for C++
# compiler flags:
#  -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
#  -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall
# the build target executable:
TARGET = test
all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c

clean:
        $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

The test.c file is a just for compilation test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("just for test \n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute make, I get the following error:

```
/project_path/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/gcc -g -Wall -o test test.c
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

What is wrong with my Makefile?

Comment: Does `/project_path/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/gcc` exist and has executable permissions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: yes /project_path/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/gcc has exec permission : -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: when I compile with CC=gcc it works fine (not cross compile)

Answer (score 1):

gcc will invoke other tools like cc1, however that program wasn't in system path in your makefile, just as @js441 tells you.

Comment: any solution to make cc1 in system path !!

Comment: echo 'export PATH=your-path/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/profile with root priviledge, then source /etc/profile.  since some linux cannot work with .bashrc