# Can't Compile Java GCJ-6.2.0 Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: java, macos, gcc, gcj

I have written a basic program in the Java programming language, and it compiles normally with Oracle Java, but when using GCJ to compile with this command "gcj-6.2.0 main.java"I get this error "gcj-6.2.0: error trying to exec 'ecj1': execvp: No such file or directory". Every other GCC compiler works fine besides Java, I am on a Mac and installed the latest version of GCC yesterday. What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)