# gcc and g++ error: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I'm having problems compiling `.c` and `.cpp` files using `gcc` and `g++`, for both cases i got the message:

```
g++(or gcc): error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory`
```

I've already tried to reinstall both gcc and `g++` and be sure that they're both in the same version.

Edits: I'm using ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, both g++ and gcc are in version 5.4.0 20160609.

The following is the output of `echo | g++ -v -xc++ -fsyntax-only -`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-fsyntax-only' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -iprefix ../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/ -D_GNU_SOURCE - -quiet -dumpbase - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase - -version -fsyntax-only -o /dev/null -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security
g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Thats the outuput of compiling a hello world program with gcc -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -iprefix ../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/ codigo.c -quiet -dumpbase codigo.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase codigo -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/cckVKe9E.s
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

The following is the output of `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus </dev/null`:

```
Analyzing compilation unit
Performing interprocedural optimizations
 <*free_lang_data> <visibility> <build_ssa_passes> <opt_local_passes> <free-inline-summary> <whole-program> <inline>Assembling functions:

Execution times (seconds)
 phase setup             :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 (20%) wall    1408 kB (81%) ggc
 phase parsing           :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 (20%) wall     318 kB (18%) ggc
 parser (global)         :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 (20%) wall     302 kB (17%) ggc
 TOTAL                 :   0.00             0.00             0.05               1746 kB
```

Comment: This question requires code and build commands.

Comment: i can't compile any code, not even a Hello World, about the build commands i just type "g++ <codename>" for example.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: What version of GCC?  From the error message it looks like you're doing this on Windows - is this MinGW or Cygwin (and specify which version).  Older versions of MinGW sometimes had trouble with finding executables, but I forget the details. If you're using something pretty old, you might want to try updating.

Comment: Check that there are no stray executables in your PATH named g++.exe or the like. Try invoking g++ with a full path.

Comment: Please run the command `echo | g++ -v -xc++ -fsyntax-only -`, and then edit your question (click on the small gray word "edit" under the tags), copy and paste the *complete, unedited* output of that command into the edit box and save.

Comment: Several questions about this error message have been posed before; many of them are linked in the sidebar.  Please check whether any of those apply to your case.  If not, please add the information necessary to distinguish yours.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, what about that error message makes you think "Windows"?  I'm inclined to think *non*-Windows, but with MinGW and Cygwin in the mix, that's not really black & white.  Certainly, however, exactly the error message reported here has been observed on Linux in the past.

Comment: This does seem suspiciously like an incorrectly installed GCC.  I wonder what `find /usr/lib -name cc1plus 2>/dev/null` would yield.

Comment: Also note that the same error message can be caused by a missing shared library.

Comment: `find /usr/lib -name cc1plus 2>/dev/null` returned: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1plus , i've installed both gcc and g++ through ubuntu repositories, via terminal.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: my mistake - I thought the error message for this kind of thing was worded differently on Linux.

Comment: Another test command: `echo | strace -f -eexecve g++ -xc++ -fsyntax-only -`

Comment: This isn't an _answer_, but just to explain a little what the problem is: The program installed as `g++` in a public "bin" directory is a wrapper. All the actual work of compilation is done by another program, `cc1plus`, which is installed in a private directory (in your case, `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/`). The error message you're getting indicates that the wrapper is failing to run the internal program. We still don't know _why_.

Comment: `echo | strace -f -eexecve g++ -xc++ -fsyntax-only -` returns: strace: Can't stat 'g++': No such file or directory

Comment: Could it be caused by an issue with 2 different versions being installed on the system? OP seems to have both gcc 4.8 and gcc 5 installed.

Comment: The commands `g++ --version` and `gcc --version` returned the exact same version, 5.4.0 20160609.

Comment: The output of `find /usr/lib -name cc1plus 2>/dev/null` indicates more than one version is installed.

Comment: @Chimera: That's usually not anything to be worried about.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-5.4`

Comment: Try running `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus </dev/null` and see if it works.  It will spit out a `gccdump.s` file in the current directory, but the contents of the file aren't interesting—what's interesting is whether the program fails.

Comment: Try running `make julianne_fries`

Comment: @Chimera: there is no package named gcc-5.4

Comment: Please, check out the answers in here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory) and see if some of the suggestion there, which also have been provided here, work for you. Change occurrences of `cc1` from the other link to `cc1plus`, which is your case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said `echo | strace -f -eexecve $(which g++) -xc++ -fsyntax-only -`.

Comment: What happens when you run /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus directly?

Comment: Also post output of `which g++` and `printenv`.

Comment: the cc1 program should be located at: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1`

Comment: Thank you for all the support, i eventually had to reinstall ubuntu , what solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Something has been broken in your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) installation (read also about GCC [environment variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) & [spec files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html)).

<sup>Check also your environment, be sure to avoid any `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` environment variables</sup>

I would suggest to re-install with [aptitude](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html):

```
aptitude reinstall gcc-5 g++-5
```

(perhaps you need to replace both occurrences of `5` by `6`, at least on newer versions of Ubuntu)

Then compile some `hello world` program with `gcc -v` to be sure it is working.

Comment: Since apparently there is no packages "gcc-6" and "g++-6" i tried with "gcc-5" and "gcc-5" , it finishes the installation but it did not solve the problem.