# Offline R packages installation on centos-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: r, installation, centos

### I am trying to install some R packages on the Centos Server that has no connection with internet.

I am following below steps-

---

---

1.Downloading package binaries on my local system

2)Transferred it on the server /tmp

3)On the server,I am running R in /tmp and running

install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL, type="source")
it asks for file  ----

Enter file name: digest_0.6.13.tar.gz

- installing *source* package ‘digest’ ...
  package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  libs
  gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c aes.c -o aes.o
  gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
  make: *** [aes.o] Error 1
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘digest’
- removing ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library/digest’
  Warning message:
  In install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL) :
  installation of package ‘digest_0.6.13.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Please assist on this.

If it is a duplicate question please redirect me,I coudnt find.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: issue got resolved.I have update gcc using "yum install gcc"