# Unable to install spacy on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: linux, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, spacy, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to load spacy into SageMaker. I run the following in Jupyter notebook instance

```
!pip install spacy
```

I end up getting this error

```
  gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and this as well

```
gcc: error: murmurhash/mrmr.cpp: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I resolve this issue withing Sagemaker?

Comment: How did you made it work? none of the solution below worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing similar problems when I started using SageMaker so I developed this open source project https://github.com/Kenza-AI/sagify (sagify), it's a CLI tool that can help you train and deploy your own Machine Learning/Deep Learning models on SageMaker in a very easy way. I managed to train and deploy all of my ML models whatever library I was using (Keras, Tensorflow, scikit-learn, LightFM, spacy, etc). Essentially, you can specify all your dependencies in the classic pythonic way, i.e. in a requiments.txt, and sagify will read them and install them on a Docker image. Then, this Docker image can be executed on SageMaker for training and deployment.

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/38733918/3276830

Fix gcc

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
```

I am not sure about second error, maybe `murmurhash/mrmr.cpp` does not exist?

Comment: I had tried this. apt-get is not recognized. So I tried yum install instead. but I get no package build-essential available

Comment: On yum, try out `yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: If that also fails, try `sudo yum install gcc-c++.noarch`

Comment: Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1039 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package gcc-c++-4.8.5-1.22.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: It should have worked, I can't say much more, you may also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48925817/3276830 , it is recent.

Answer (score -1):

You can try following commands to install spacy, using Jupyter cell selecting Python3 kernel

```
!conda update --all -y 
!conda install -n python3 -y -c conda-forge spacy
```

and then restart the kernel.

After restarting the kernel you should be able to import spacy. Or you can issue the same above commands using Jupyter terminal, just remove ! mark when issuing commands from the above.