# AWS Elastic Beanstalk "gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a django project, which makes use of MSSQL Server. I am trying to deploy it using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

I have GCC and G++ working on my computer, so I am not sure why that is causing any problems here. I searched around and wasnt able to find any solution that is directly related to mine, and I am not sure where to move forward from here.

Here is the requirements.txt

```
astroid==1.6.5
awsebcli==3.14.6
botocore==1.12.9
cement==2.8.2
colorama==0.3.9
Django==2.0.6
django-mssql==1.8
django-pyodbc-azure==2.0.6.1
django-sendgrid-v5==0.6.893
docutils==0.14
future==0.16.0
isort==4.3.4
jmespath==0.9.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mysql-connector-python-rf==2.2.2
pathspec==0.5.5
pylint==1.9.2
PyMySQL==0.8.1
pyodbc==4.0.23
pypyodbc==1.3.3.1
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-http-client==3.1.0
pytz==2018.5
PyYAML==3.13
semantic-version==2.5.0
sendgrid==5.4.1
six==1.11.0
style==1.1.0
termcolor==1.1.0
update==0.0.1
urllib3==1.22
wrapt==1.10.11
```

This is my log, specifically the eb-activity section

---

### /var/log/eb-activity.log

```
    Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyodbc: started
    Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyodbc: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1cdwy0uv/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpxf7u3lwwpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.23 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/pyodbcmodule.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/pyodbcmodule.o -Wno-write-strings
    gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 
 Failed building wheel for pyodbc
    Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
  Failed to build pyodbc
  Installing collected packages: pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure, future, python-http-client, sendgrid, django-sendgrid-v5, isort, mccabe, mysql-connector-python-rf, pylint, PyMySQL, pypyodbc, style, update
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc: started
      Running setup.py install for pyodbc: finished with status 'error'
      Complete output from command /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1cdwy0uv/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wpg4l1dm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/python/run/venv/include/site/python3.6/pyodbc:
      running install
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'pyodbc' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.23 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/pyodbcmodule.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/pyodbcmodule.o -Wno-write-strings
      gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: This is a `pyodbc` problem. Looks like it has a C++ interface, the compilation of which is failing. The EC2 machine you are running this on potentially lacks a necessary linkage library.

Comment: There are some suggestions in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory). As you are a new contributor, for future reference, it is considered best-practice to determine whether the question you are trying to answer has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not already have a `.ebextensions` directory, then create one, and add a file named `01_packages.config` to it with the following content:

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    unixODBC-devel: []
```

When you run `eb deploy` at your console, then the config files in the `.ebextensions` directory will be processed before AWS runs `pip install` on your `requirements.txt` file, and you should have the right packages installed for your `pypyodbc==1.3.3.1` requirement.

Comment: Great solution. Works also for similar pycld2 error.