# Execution failing while running from browser

Tags: php, gcc, exec, shell-exec

I am building online compiler for C and C++ using php, so we are using `gcc compiler` to execute using "shell_exec" function ,

> test.php

`<?php
 $output = shell_exec("gcc /var/www/test/main.c  2>&1");
 print_R($output);
?>`

If I execute in terminal like `php test.php`, is working fine and it is creating `a.out` compiled file.

But If I try to run in the browser like `localhost/test.php`, its giving below error

> gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

I gave full permission (0777) to `test.php`,

> $ whereis cc1  // cc1:

Please find below version I am using

> gcc version 5.4.0
>
> PHP 7.0.32
>
> OS: ubuntu 16.04
>
> server : Nginx

Is there any alternate to run C and C++ using PHP or how to resolve this issue whille running from the browser.

Comment: It becouse gcc is root's program. In terminal you can run it (your profile can run root's programs). But brouser starts other user (like www-data, or other). And it user cant run root's programs

Comment: @Vasyl Zhuryk, thanks for the reply, is there anyway to fix this or any alternate method for this?

Comment: That is not secure, but you can try: `ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc` It creates symbolic link to program without root privileges

Comment: Does this `gcc /var/www/test/main.c` complete successfully when executed from a shell on the server itself?

Comment: @alk, yes it execute successfully while running from terminal

Comment: @Vasyl, I created sym link in /usr/local/bin/gcc, still error gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Comment: @Abhi can you try this code? `shell_exec("/usr/bin/gcc /var/www/test/main.c  2>&1");`

Comment: @Vasyl , its giving now error as , collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld' compilation terminated

Comment: @Abhi can you show your `main.c` file?

Comment: @ Vasyl Zhuryk , #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello....");
  return 0;
}

Comment: @Abhi I tried to do it in my computer - all done right. In your case can help this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @Vasyl Zhuryk - Can I know your gcc and ubuntu version

Comment: @Abhi `$ gcc -v
...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)`

Comment: @Abhi `PHP 7.1.23-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 15 2018 11:36:43) ( NTS )` Also I added my user to apache user (in your case nginx user)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message, the problem comes from two issues:

- `php` cannot find `gcc` since `$path` variable is not correctly set, in `php` file, you should type something like `PATH=/usr/bin && gcc /var/www/test/main.c`. In this example, `gcc` and other stuff are in `/usr/bin` directory. To know where are located `cc1` for instance, type `find / -name cc1` and add it to `$PATH`: `PATH=/some/path:/some/other/path`
- Current directory of `php` could no be writtable, so indicate where the generated file must be created: `gcc /var/www/test/main.c -o /var/www/test/main`
- Directory `/var/www/test` must be writable by user running `php` program.

Note that the user running the `php` program is not necessary the `root`...

So your php file should looks like:

```
<?php
 $output = shell_exec("PATH=/usr/bin && gcc /var/www/test/main.c -o/var/www/test/main 2>&1");    
 print_R($output);
?>
```

Comment: Hello purplepsycho, still I am getting same error gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Comment: @ purplepsycho, I updated path as , PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1, still the same error

Comment: @Abhi Do not put the `cc1` in path

Comment: still the same for  shell_exec("PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/ && gcc /var/www/test/compiler/test/main.c -o/var/www/test/compiler/test/main 2>&1");