# Eclipse IDE - Gluon Plugin - cc1 not found - Debian GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, debian, gluon

I'm trying to use the Gluon Plugin on Eclipse IDE on Debian GNU/Linux... The project is configured to build using maven. Yet it doesn't find "cc1" even if it's installed as well as gcc and g++ and build-essential...

The log file says:

```
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:17 COT 2020][INFO] ==================== COMPILE TASK ====================
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:18 COT 2020][FINE] PB Command for check version: /home/mateo/AppsFiles/graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0/bin/java -version
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:18 COT 2020][FINE] Start process check version...
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] [SUB] openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] [SUB] OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 20.2.0 (build 11.0.8+10-jvmci-20.2-b03)
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] [SUB] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.2.0 (build 11.0.8+10-jvmci-20.2-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] Result for check version: 0
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][INFO] We will now compile your code for x86_64-linux-linux. This may take some time.
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] Extracting native libs to: /home/mateo/Workspace/Java/TestGluon/target/client/x86_64-linux/gvm/lib
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] Looking for resource: /native/linux/launcher.c
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] PB Command for compile-additional-sources: gcc -c -DSUBSTRATE -I/home/mateo/AppsFiles/graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0/include -I/home/mateo/AppsF$
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] Start process compile-additional-sources...
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] [SUB] gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][FINE] Result for compile-additional-sources: 1
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][SEVERE] Process compile-additional-sources failed with result: 1
Check the log files under /home/mateo/Workspace/Java/TestGluon/target/client/x86_64-linux/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/ for more information.
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][INFO] Logging process [compile-additional-sources] to file: /home/mateo/Workspace/Java/TestGluon/target/client/log/process-compile-additional-so$
[Wed Sep 23 10:34:19 COT 2020][SEVERE] Compiling failed.
Check the log files under /home/mateo/Workspace/Java/TestGluon/target/client/x86_64-linux/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/ for more information.
```

The important part is:

```
[SUB] gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

because it doesn't find cc1... Is there any way to tell Eclipse IDE where is that located at?
Thanks.

Comment: A quick search of your issue shows this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory), which is mainly related to the proper installation of `gcc`. FYI, [these](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml#L23) are the packages installed by the CI to do testing by the plugin on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and for correcting my crappy post... I installed all the development libraries, reconfigured the build-essential package as well as g++ and gcc. Yet the issue remains and the log file is the same...

Comment: Are you running from a terminal? What gives you `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1`?

Comment: It prints "cc1."

Comment: For me it shows: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1`, and `which gcc` prints `/usr/bin/gcc` which is a symlink to `gcc-9`, which is symlink to `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9`. Do you have such files?

Comment: `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` is showing `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1` and `which gcc` prints the same symlink...

Comment: Can't say what is wrong with your setup. Probably worth uninstalling `build-essential`, and installing it again?

Comment: I did that... Purged it, uninstalled it. Reinstalled the entire OS... I'm trying another machine and the error is the same... My luck I guess... I've got another laptop who's showing this as well... `Fatal error:java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.gluonapplication.views.primary, locale en_US`

Comment: Update the Gluon plugin for Eclipse and then create a new project, that should work.

Comment: I reinstalled Eclipse IDE as well as Debian 3 times now... The same error keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in order to make it work.

1. I reinstalled the entire OS.
2. I installed build-essential, gcc and g++. (Even if I had them before...)
3. I deleted my workspace as well as Eclipse completely.
4. I deleted the GRAALVM_HOME variable and all the files it pointed at.
5. I installed GraalVM on /opt.
6. I installed Eclipse (Not the Snap version) The Gluon Plugin and Efxclipse.
7. It didn't work again... I installed maven replaced the Eclipse one with the newly installed one.
8. It didn't work one more time yet I saw the logs so I had to export the GRAALVM_HOME variable as an environment variable on the project...
9. I had to install more development packages:

`xvfb tigervnc-standalone-server tigervnc-common at-spi2-core build-essential libgtk-3-dev libxtst-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libasound2-dev libgl-dev`

(A person on the comments helped me with those.)